# how to save changes made to a jtable

Tags: java, netbeans, jtable, jcombobox

I have created a jtable that hosts a cell that is a combobox I can get the combobox to populate the jtable but once I restart the program the cells become completely empty. I need a way to save the changes so that once the program is restarted the changes made will remain.( Noted: I have searched solutions for this but to no advance.)

```
     String path ="C:\\Users\\GrantAJ\\Documents\\Comment Matrix";
File folder = new File(path);'File[] listOfFiles= folder.listFiles();
////// filters file objects in java to populate jcombobox with just the name ///// 
List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();
for(File files1: listOfFiles){
if(files1.isFile()){
fileNames.add(files1.getName());
}else if (files1.isDirectory())
{ System.out.print("Directory : );
}
final JComboBox jList1 = new JComboBox(listOfFiles);


 jList1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
  {
    @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, files1.getName());
}
});
TableColumn col = jTable_Files_Name.getColumnModel().getColumn(4);
col.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(jList1));
}



 Object[] row = new Object[6];

// fill the rows and columns
    row[0] = file.getName();
    row[1] = file.getAbsolutePath();
    row[2]= dt;
    row[3]=sb.toString();
    row[4]=files1.getName();
    row[5]=hostname;


model.addRow(new Object []{row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],"",row[5]});

} 

 }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to build an "AbstractTableModel".
This table model will contains your data and could be saved.

To load your model, call new JTable(your_model).

You can look here for more help : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data

Good luck.